# Ceramic capacitors shorting on power up

Tags: capacitor, switch-mode-power-supply, short-circuit, decoupling-capacitor

I have a power supply unit that is used to drive a couple of relays. Rarely but sometimes the input capacitors (C218, C200, C201 and C207) to the switch (U202) short when the power is turned on (230V.) Sometimes it is only one of the capacitors that is shorted (often C200,) sometimes it is all of them. We couldn't find the reason and put in a TVS (R215) after the filter in desperate move but the capacitors keep shorting. Does anyone have clue what could cause this?

Note, GND is connected to PE on this card.

- Fs = 800kHz
- Vin= 22V
- Vout= 12V (not 10V)

PDF:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/45owhv6dmq6l7ti/POWER.pdf?dl=0

Schematic:
[image]

---

To answer some of your questions:

- All caps between L202 and the switch are ceramic caps, the only electronytic is the bulk one after rectifier.
- The system has been ESD-tested. Up to 4kV on the mains with no problem, the TVS's seems to deals with those spikes fine.
- This is a rare fault on these cards. It does not happen to every card. More like 1 of 200 or something.
- When the cards fail, the caps usually dont blow up, they look fine but are shorted. No soot or signs of stress/heat.
  Historically we have gotten 1 or 2 cards with blown up caps(leaving a crater in the pcb), but those are very rare. It is however that exact capacitor bank before the switch that blows up.

Here is a picture of the power up. Measured on VIN (U202). Voltage is 1/10 on the scale.
[image: Measured on VIN (U202).]

Comment: What's the half component on the left of the picture? What's the AC voltage across pins 2/3 of D201? How does the 230 V mains get to C218? The attached png, while a lot better than nothing, is still mostly illegible at that scale, and incomplete. You're having trouble with mains switch-on killing C218? Show the entire path, legibly, from mains to C218.

Comment: And make your component IDs and names bigger.

Comment: didnt find a good way to post schematic. added dropbox link to pdf

Comment: Have the capacitors been physically stressed? Too close to edge of the pcb?

Comment: Not that we now. The caps are placed beside the transformer, at least 10mm from pcb edge. There are other caps in the same area that never fails so it should not be pcb stress that causes this.

Comment: Do you have a scope capable of measuring the voltage on caps? It could be that during the inrush, the inductor gives  big spike as the capacitors charge, higher then their maxium voltage

Comment: Have you looked on a scope to see what the voltage waveform is like on power-up? Note that under EMI rules spikes on mains up to 4kV should be tolerated.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "short." Are the caps blowing up? I don't see any issues with your schematic that will mess up these capacitors, assuming of course that you are using nonpolarized caps.

Comment: It strikes me that a discharged capacitor is *supposed* to be a dead short intially, that's what capacitance is. Could you please explain how your "shorts" differ from this natural behaviour?

Comment: Those are huge values for ceramics, obviously very high K ceramic. I notice they're all different values, following the 'decouple all frequencies' philosophy that I find very dubious. I wonder if the LM25011 is drawing a current frequency that puts one of them into series resonance? They will all have different SRFs, and the large ones will go inductive, and a high Q resonance could kill them. With its 45 V abs max, the LM25011 may not blow as a result. You would need a 'scope to see, OR, put a 1 ohm resistor in series with each to reduce the Q as an experiment (not as a permanent fix)

Comment: Tagging on to @Neil_UK posit on resonance, I have found that circuits such as yours with the 12uH inductor and capacitors on the right side of the inductor will ring with current spikes. You can have ring voltages that may grossly exceed the voltage rating of your capacitors. My solution was to de-Q the inductor by placing a 10 ohm resistor across the inductor.

Comment: Input voltage overshoot seems the most likely explanation. Check application note 88 (AN88). https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/an88f.pdf

Comment: Some ceramic capacitors will produce a substantial voltage spike far above the supplied voltage when hit with a sharp voltage transient. These spikes can destroy connected semiconductors so presumably also other caps when multiple  parallel  caps are used. IF this is the cause then turn in and maybe off management may help confirm this cause. Note that worst case inductor input is zero crossing point and Vinmax for caps. Large value of C206 suggests turn off spike more likely.

Comment: Can you include a scope capture of the voltage across those caps while the circuit is running (before changing the circuit)?

Comment: That spike at powerup look suspect; there's clearly significant ringing. You need to inspect it at a much smaller timescale; currently you're at 100ms/div. Zoom in by a factor 10,000 or so.

Comment: *** CLOSE VOTERS *** - would you please tell me WHY you voted to close. Everyone is entitled to their opinion but itwould be useful to know what people found wrong here.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon It seems to me that some people have nothing better to do, and want to feel useful and powerful at the same time, voting to close a post just because they can, not because there is a good reason for it. This question here is thought-provocative and helps get an insight into unexpected circuit problems. My question was closed as well, reasons that were cited were not to be found in my post, such as "promoting specific product, manufacturer or distributor"; it was as generic as it could get.

Comment: @EdinFifić  I'm a moderator. I see all sorts of views and interpretations and try to accommodate as many as I reasonably can. Many of those who are active in voting to close are competent sight members and the majority probably have a genuine desire to keep the site close to what the rules suggest. I personally feel that the rules tend to be less permissive than I feel is useful BUT I don't set the rules and usually "go with the flow". ...

Comment: @EdinFifić ... || I assume the question you refer to was your [MOSFET selection question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/586225/3288) - in my opinion it was quite likely to be useful to enough people for long enough to be worth leaving open **BUT** it was definitely against site rules. I had no part in closing it but understand the motives of those who did.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Thank you. I understand. I find this site as a useful outlet for finding answers and explanations or solutions to some of my circuit problems. Often, while answering a question, I get more insight into the issue as well, so I basically help myself while helping others. In this question here, I can see multiple reasons and approaches to the problem and the ways of solving it, and I can barely wait to hear what was the real reason and what has worked. I feel like being in a room with technicians, engineers and scientists, all suggesting a solution until the problem is solved.

Comment: @Jake I haven't seen any updates or responses from you to my inquiries. Can you please post a scope shot of voltage surges across those caps during normal operation, and let us know if you have tried my suggestions and what has worked for you? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Your L202 together with the switcher (U202 - LM25011) acts as a boost converter. Every time the switcher switches off, the inductor dumps its energy in the form of a high voltage spike into those capacitors, eventually destroying them.
If you have an oscilloscope handy, try to capture these spikes. I am curious to see them.
I would suggest to try each of these things separately:

1. Split the 3300uF input capacitor into 2 capacitors of around 1000-2200uF, and place them on each side of the L202. Right now you have a very large cap on the input side, but much smaller caps on the other side of L202, giving you a solid/stiff DC on the left, but a significantly higher impedance on the right, incapable of sinking the spikes from L202, or sourcing the whole current to the switcher without resulting in voltage "dips" during the ON part of its cycle. You basically have voltage dips on the right side of L202 during the ON part of the switcher cycle, and voltage spikes coming from L202 during the switcher's OFF part of its cycle; you're "pumping" the L202 in a way.
   If the L202 only had to block smaller currents of high frequency harmonics (which I believe is its intended purpose), it wouldn't be acting this way.
2. Remove L202 from the circuit.

---

P.S.: I would love to see your scope capture across those caps before and after the suggested modification, and that you let me know if it worked for you. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what Dr Moishe Pippick said - the surge suppressors are rated at a dangerously high voltage - even more so than his comment suggests.

While this is nominally a 26V suppressor, it is rated at a clamp voltage of

33.2V at 1mA
42.1V at 14.2A

As others have noted, a sudden removal of load turns C217 & L302 into a boost converter. Depending on various in-component and stray capacitances & inductances voltage may well be able to exceed the 35V capacitor voltage ratings.

Changing to a SMBJ20 would allow about 32V max at 18A but is almost certainly too close to the initial breakdown voltage to be usable.

Changing to an SMBJ22 with a breakdown voltage of 24.4 V minimum may prove satisfactory and would be worth trying.

Adding a modest additional resistive load to the 22V rail (maybe lowering R209, R210 or a separate resistor) would help reduce peak Voc. An input clamp zener dissipating minimal wattage at 22V but very usefully more at slightly above that may be a useful complement to the surge protectors.

Even an SMBJ24 provides very useful clamping at 35V and is rated at Vrwm_min of 24 volts and Vbr of 26.7V.

[image]

Comment: That's what I have realized about TVS components; their voltage range is very wide. For most of my purposes, I have found that zener diodes rated for at least 1W act sufficiently well, and have significantly narrower active voltage range. At less than 1W, zeners don't respond fast enough, they just don't cut the peaks off, probably because they can't absorb enough current.

Answer (score 0):

The [SMBJ26CA transient suppression diodes](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/diodes/ds19002.pdf) have a *nominal* 26 V rating, but the peak is shown as 33.2 V, perilously close to the 35 volt rating of the capacitors. Use caps with higher voltage rating. At ~US$4 per cap, they're a bit pricey to blow out frequently.

Comment: They are in parallel with the 3300uF cap that is shown as polarized so I suspect the schematic is correct and those 22uF and 10uF caps are ceramics.

Comment: @KevinWhite, Sorry, I had not known 22 µF caps existed! Mouser does carry them, and I'll amend the answer.